# Smart Map - Output map locations from relationship file in a matrix

Tags: matrix, relations, plugin-smartmap

I have "locations" section where each entry is a location, with a Smart Map field for the address.

I have another section "pages", where I have a matrix field which contains an entry relationship field, where I can select entries (locations) from the first channel.

I'm trying to output a map of all locations selected in my matrix field, but I'm getting an error:
Property "Craft\SmartMap_AddressModel.title" is not defined.

I'm using the code below to get the address fields from the individual entries, and put them into an array. I think maybe I'm not understanding what exactly needs to be in the locations array:

```
{% set locations = [] %}

{#  loop though all relationship fields for this entry #}
{% for block in entry.pageBuilder.type('listingGroup') %}

    {#  loop through related entries #}
    {% for member in block.listing %}

        {# get individual entry address #}
        {% set address = member.address %}

        {# add entry address to locations array #}
        {% set locations = locations|merge([address])%}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{{ craft.smartMap.map(locations, options) }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance, your code *looks* perfect... but I think there's a subtle error. The `locations` parameter can be an array of **elements**, but you are building an array of **Address fields** (which is not valid).

> https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/render-a-map-in-twig/

[image: locations]

You can simplify the middle part of your code to this:

```
{# add entry to locations array #}
{% set locations = locations|merge([member]) %}
```

That way, `locations` will end up being **an array of elements**.

Comment: That did it. Makes sense. I think in my head, doing it that way didn't seem specific enough.

Comment: Is it possible to get reverse relationship data back out of my locations array? Each matrix block has a field for venueType, in addition to my relationship field. I'd like to be able to get the venueType data for each location to create custom icons. {% set venues = craft.entries.section('members','events').relatedTo({
    targetElement: entry,
    field: 'myMatrix.matrixRelationshipField'
}) %} doesn't work.

Comment: Figured it out:     {% set venue = entry.featuredMembers.myMatrix.relatedTo(location).first() %} 
    {{ venue.venueType }}

Comment: @artmem That sounds like a completely unrelated question, and should probably be asked as a new thread (for future reference).